# cant subtract 2 timstamp long values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-date

i'm trying to subtract two long(timestamp) but it kept crashing the application
heres the code

```kotlin
//converting timestamp to actual time;
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
        calendar.timeInMillis = chat!!.timestamp!!.toLong()

        val t24 = 86400000 //24hrs in milliseconds
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
        val chatTime: Int = chat.timestamp!!.toInt()
        val date = holder.date

        if ((currentTime - chatTime ) < t24 ) {
            val time =
                DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendar).toString()
            date!!.text = time
        }else{

            val time =
                DateFormat.format("dd/MM//yyyy hh:mm aa", calendar).toString()
            date!!.text = time

        }
```

and this is the error

```html
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1594502477561"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:618)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.google.meetchat.Adapters.ChatAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ChatAdapter.kt:64)
        at com.google.meetchat.Adapters.ChatAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ChatAdapter.kt:18)
```

line 64 is where chatTIme Variable is initialized

Comment: Write down the crash, it's crucial.

Comment: You should mention the crash logs or Exceptions they may have thrown. What I think of currently is mostly because of NullPointerException, since you've used unsafe operator (`!!`) on nullable values.

Comment: You did not post the code related to the error. Debug to find which line of your code throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [**not-null assertion operator**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) (`!!`) on some variables. It converts any value to a **non-null** type and **throws an exception** if the value is **null**.

I suspect you are getting `NullPointerException` when you use that operator on a variable. Please make sure that these variables are initialized before using operator `!!` on them:

*chat, chat.timestamp, holder.date*

UPDATE:

Please use `Long` for timestamps, don't convert them to `Int`. For example replace:

```
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
val chatTime: Int = chat.timestamp!!.toInt()
```

with:

```
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val chatTime = chat.timestamp!!.toLong()
```

That's because timestamps are represented in milliseconds (or seconds if it is Unix timestamp) and the value can be higher than max value of `Int` type which is `public const val MAX_VALUE: Int = 2147483647`.